# How can I subtract two time that entered in two maskedtextbox and show it into third maskedtextbox?

Tags: c#, timespan

I can't convert text ( in `Maskedtextbox`) to a `Datetime`.
For example I have these times in maskes: `16:30`, `6:30`
I want to show in third masked  `10:00`
HERE is my codes: I write a method

I have an error in line: timespan t
the error is: input string was not in a correct format

Public void A (MaskedTextBox k, MaskedTextBox k1, MaskedTextBox k2, Label k3)
     {
     string[] houre = k.Text.Split(':');
     try
     {
     int h = int.Parse (houre[0].ToString();
     int m = int.Parse (houre[1].ToString();

```
            if (h > 23)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong hour");
                k.Text = "00:" + houre[1].ToString();
            }
            if (m > 59)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong minute");
                k.Text = houre[0].ToString() + ":00";
            }
            if (h > 23 && m > 59)

                k.Text = "00:00";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        string[] houre1 = k1.Text.Split(':');
        try
        {
            int h1 = int.Parse(houre1[0].ToString());
            int m1 = int.Parse(houre1[1].ToString());

            if (h1 > 23)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong hour");
                k1.Text = "00:" + houre1[1].ToString();
            }
            if (m1 > 59)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong minute");
                k1.Text = houre1[0].ToString() + ":00";
            }
            if (h1 > 23 && m1 > 59)

                k1.Text = "00:00";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.ParseExact(k.Text.Trim(':'), "hh:mm",null );
        TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(k1.Text, "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        k2.Text = (t1 - t).ToString("hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


        if (k.Text != "" && k1.Text != "")
            k3.Text = "IN OUT Complete";
        else
         k3.Text = "IN OUT Noncomplete";
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Try a `Timespan` rather than a `DateTime`, assuming both times are on the same day

Comment: Do you always want to show a positive number, or is one time considered "first" and the other should be subtracted from it, even if it's a greater number?

Answer (score 1):

You actually work with `TimeSpan` (not `DateTime`); you should `Parse`, do *arithmetics* and, finally, format the result as `String`:

```
  TimeSpan left = TimeSpan.ParseExact(
    maskedBox1.Text.Trim(), "h\\:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  TimeSpan right = TimeSpan.ParseExact(
    maskedBox2.Text.Trim(), "h\\:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  myMaskedBox.Text = (left - right).ToString("hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Dear . the times ( like 6:30) must entered by person in maskedtextboxes . we cant write numbers in our codes

Comment: @mohsenbahar: well, we can easily put `SomeMaskedBox.Text` instead of (demo) values

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.' ( in the frist line( left))

Comment: @mohsenbahar: what are the strings which you put into `maskedBox`? Could you put a *breakpoint* and inspect `maskedBox1.Text`? You may want to get rid of whitespaces, padding etc.

Comment: my maskedtexbos is set to europe time( 11:30) this box fill by user

Comment: @mohsenbahar: I see; however it seems that the *actual* `string` is not exactly `"11:30"` but contains *extra characters* (say, whitespaces) something like `" 11:30 "`. Leading / Trailing spaces can be removed by simple `.Trim()`; if the string contains whitespaces within itself they can be removed by Linq: `string.Concat(maskedBox1.Text.Where(c => c != char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following codes:

'''

```
        var timeString1 = "16:30";
        var timeString2 = "6:30";

        //Make sure the parse input string match the HH:mm format
        timeString1 = timeString1.PadLeft(5, '0');
        timeString2 = timeString2.PadLeft(5, '0');

        var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString1, "HH:mm", null);
        var time2 = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString2, "HH:mm", null);
        var timeSpan12 = time1 - time2;

        var result = $"{timeSpan12.Hours:d2}:{timeSpan12.Minutes:d2}";
        Console.WriteLine(result);//10:30
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

### I find good way :

public static long Time(string t)
        {
            return
                   (long.Parse(t.Substring(0,2)) * TimeSpan.TicksPerHour)+
                   (long.Parse(t.Substring(3,2))*TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute);

### }

public void Calculate(MaskedTextBox a,MaskedTextBox b,MaskedTextBox c)
        {

```
        if (Time(b.Text) > Time(a.Text))
        {
            long q;
            q = (Time(b.Text) - Time(a.Text)) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
            c.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(q).ToString();
        }
        if (Time(b.Text) < Time(a.Text))
        {
            long q;
            q = ((Time(b.Text)+24*TimeSpan.TicksPerHour) - Time(a.Text)) / 
                 TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
            c.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(q).ToString();
        }
        if (Time(b.Text) == Time(a.Text))
            c.Text = "00:00";

    }
```